# Filtering collection inside collection of object is not working

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am trying to filter a sublist inside list using LINQ Any operator, the problem that Any operator is not working despite it is an approved answer for such problem in many sites, 
I have List of Group objects that each Group Object has a list Vehicles, the problem I am trying to filter the vehicles inside each group using Plate Number

Please Check the code below that I created for checking this problem

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Seed seed = new Seed();
            seed.SeedGroupsVehicles();
            List<Group> lstGrps =seed.SeedGroupsVehicles();
            // Linq Query to filter Vehicles inside each group 
            var filtered = lstGrps
                .Where(s => s.Vehicles.Any(vehicle => vehicle.PlateNo.Contains("A0-")))
                .GroupBy(p=>p.Name);
            List<Group> lstfilteredGroup = filtered.SelectMany(f => f).ToList();
            // Print Filtered Groups 
            foreach(var grp in lstfilteredGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Group {0} {1}" , grp.Id,grp.Name);
                foreach (var vehicle in grp.Vehicles)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tVehicle {0} {1} {2}",vehicle.Id,vehicle.Name,vehicle.PlateNo);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class Seed
    {
        public List<Group> SeedGroupsVehicles()
        {
            // Create two groups each group has ten vehicles 
            Group[] arrGroups = new Group[2];
            string[] vehiclesPLateNums = new string[] { "A0-3456790", "A0-3440999", "A0-2354543", "A0-5345346", "LP-ZA32554", "LP-3445464", "LP-3590324", "LP-3423535", "LP-2352569", "LP-5435XCF" };
            string[] vehiclesNames = new string[] { "V1", "V2", "V3", "V14", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10" };
            List<Vehicle> lstvehicles;
            for (int index = 0; index < arrGroups.Length; index++)
            {
                lstvehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
                Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
                for (int vehicleIndex = 0; vehicleIndex < vehiclesNames.Length; vehicleIndex++)
                {
                    lstvehicles.Add(new Vehicle() { Id= vehicleIndex + 1 , Name=vehiclesNames[vehicleIndex],PlateNo=vehiclesPLateNums[vehicleIndex] });
                }
                arrGroups[index] =  new Group() { Id = index+1, Name = "group " + index+1, Vehicles = lstvehicles } ; 
            }
            return arrGroups.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

After printing the vehicles of each group, I noticed that the vehicles at each group are not filtered based on PlateNo that has the string "A0", 
Please Help and many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Let's say you went up to everyone and asked them whether (`Where`) they had a child where part of their name was `Matt` (`Any` and `Contains`). Sally has two children - Matthew and Cathy. She meets the criteria. If you ask her what are the names of her children, how would she answer? How might you apply to that your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is filtering `lstGrps` while you want to filter each group `Vehicles` list.

In your code `filtered` will be an `IEnumerable<Group>` where each `Group` has at least one `Vehicle` in `Vehicles` that its `PlatNo` contains `"A0-"`, and because this condition is true with all `Group`s, then nothing will be filtered.

Try this code:

```
Seed seed = new Seed();
var groups = seed.SeedGroupsVehicles();
var filteredGroups = groups
    .Select(g => new Group {
        Id = g.Id,
        Name = g.Name,
        // Here is where you filter Vehicles
        Vehicles = g.Vehicles.Where(v => v.PlateNo.Contains("A0-")),
    });
```